# How to include out of stock option price to bundle product price?

Tags: magento2, bundle, magento2bundleproduct

Whenever a required bundle option becomes out of stock, the parent product is out of stock and that particular child product amount gets deducted from the bundle product amount. I don't want to deduct that child product amount from the bundle product price. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any luck with this as I have exact same issue, confusing for customers I feel if it is required it should just show out of stock but maintain the correct price.